# Issue with running deploy command on Sitecore 10.2 JSS NextJS SXA

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

When I am initiating Sitecore JSS app with Nextjs,

```
npx create-sitecore-jss --templates nextjs,nextjs-sxa --appName sitecore-nextjs-app --hostName s102demo1cm.dev.local --fetchWith GraphQL
```

`./Sitecore` folder just has config folder, however, when I am trying to deploy items with following command:

```
jss deploy app -c -d
```

It is looking for pipelines folder and definitions folder and throwing errors:

```
JSS is creating a manifest for sitecore-jss-site to ./sitecore/manifest...
Enabling TypeScript transpilation for the manifest...
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.js' did not match any files.
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.ts' did not match any files.
Error generating manifest Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
```

and

```
JSS is creating a manifest for sitecore-jss-site to ./sitecore/manifest...
Error generating manifest Error: Unable to load manifest require C:\kk\JSS\sitecore-jss-site\sitecore\definitions\config.js: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\kk\JSS\sitecore-jss-site\sitecore\definitions\config.js'
Require stack:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a JSS app `manifest manually, by running the [JSS CLI command jss manifest](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/19/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-javascript-rendering-sdk-cli-tools-api-reference.html#UUID-ba8bae12-5938-63d2-1ae1-451aec88abe5_UUID-b94c3b68-3742-0733-e40c-e1678664e2e4).

The command `jss manifest` has options that enable modifying how the manifest generates, such as `--includeContent` to add content and routes data to the manifest. Run `jss manifest --help` to see all the options with descriptions.

Manifest does not include content, media, or dictionary items by default for safety, in case a content editor has changed the data. To include these items, run `jss manifest --includeContent --includeDictionary` to include everything.

Reference Links:

[Generating a JSS app manifest file](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/19/sitecore-headless-development/generating-a-jss-app-manifest-file.html)

[Sitecore JavaScript Rendering SDK CLI Tools API reference](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/19/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-javascript-rendering-sdk-cli-tools-api-reference.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Manifest can generate manifest folder but not definitions